# Tomcat HTML 404 on One of 17 Servers

Tags: tomcat, http-status-code-404

I have 17 tomcat (8.5.20) Linux servers that are supposedly identically provisioned behind a load balancer.  On 16 of the servers with the URL .../assets/MyHostName, I get an HTML 200 with an appropriate response.  But, on one of the servers with the same URL, I get a HTML 404 error.  If I rename all MyHostName files to MyHostName.txt, I get an HTML 200 on the one problematic server, but the other 16 servers fail with HTML 404.

I discovered this using a looping curl command to brute force my way through all tomcat servers.

I created the HostName file using the Linux command `echo $HOSTNAME -  $(hostname -I) > MyHostName`, which results in something like "XXXXXpxesauva09 - 172.25.185.233".  The file ownership and permissions are the same across all servers (owned by tomcat).

All files (css, png, etc.) within the assets subdirectory appear to be available via a URL on all servers.  What is going on with the one Tomcat server?

Answer (score 0):

Will, without more details, I can only give you some things to check:
1- check the catalina.out if the app is deployed
2- check if there is an alias (tomcat 8+) declared on the context configuration (server.xml), if there is one or more make sure you are using your curl with the right dns hostname 
3- check if the path of the webapp is the correct one (server.xml)
4- check if there some specific jar loaders (catalina.properties, the property is common.loader and should contain only standard jars unless you have some specific requirements).

Comment: The following files were compared with a tool between working servers and non-working server:
catalina.properties are identical
web.xml are identical
server.xml are identical except <Server port="xxx" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">

Comment: so have you checked the start log traces?